# VSCode - Launch.json specify arguments

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, launch

I am using the dotenv package to inject environment variables to my OS which I can specify by calling the following:

`node -r dotenv/config dist/app.js`

How can I run the same command from launch.json? Currently I have the following but it doesn't load the dotenv package

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\dist\\app.js",
"args": [
   "-r dotenv/config"
 ],
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this as one of the keys instead of `args`:

```
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "-r",
        "dotenv/config"
    ]
```